# Javascript or JQuery: click a radiobutton

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button

http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/untbe/

```
<body style="text-align:center">
  <a>
   HOW TO check a button
  </a>
       <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  >
 <input name="btn1" id="a1" type="radio" value="1"  />
            <label for="a1">1 populate USA</label>
            <input name="btn1" id="a2" type="radio"  />
            <label for="a2" class="bigga">2 populate Germany</label>

    </fieldset>
```

How to make a button selected?

```
document.getElementById('a2').attr('checked', 'checked')

jQuery("#a2").attr('checked', true);
jQuery("input[value='1']").attr('checked', true);
jQuery('input:radio[name="type"]').filter('[value="1"]').attr('checked', true);
```

I have tried all the methods i found in other threads and none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general sense if you have a direct reference to the DOM element you can just set the `.checked` property:

```
document.getElementById('a2').checked = true;
```

...or if you are using jQuery use the `.prop()` method:

```
$("#a2").prop("checked", true);
```

However, I notice in your fiddle that you are using jQuery mobile, which adds special styling and the element displayed to the user isn't the actual radio button element. For that case, as explained at the bottom of the [jQuery mobile radio buttons doco page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html), if you set the checked state with JS you then need to call `.checkboxradio("refresh")` to tell jQuery mobile to update the display:

```
$("#a2").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/untbe/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery wrapper to use methods like .attr(), but to set the checked property you need to use .prop()

```
$('#a2').prop('checked', true);
$y('input[name="type"][value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
```

using vanila javascript

```
document.getElementById('a2').checked = true
```

Comment: here's a plnk that you can check out.http://plnkr.co/edit/vhyWeTi8ixlsradfCeVN?p=preview